# Is it less computer intensive to load and unload an image every time a new image is needed or to have all of the images loaded at once? (SDL)

Tags: c++, c++11, sdl

I've created a small animation for a game that uses a set of images as frames, and the current image to render changes over a certain amount of time to create the animation illusion. I've done this in two different ways, and I'm wondering which one is more efficient to use.

**Method 1:**
A single image is loaded and rendered. When a different image needs to be rendered, a function is called that unloads the current image, and loads and renders the new one.

**Method 2:**
All of the images needed for the animation are loaded once, and then rendered as needed.

***In simpler terms:*** Method 1 unloads the current image and loads the new one every time a different image is needed, and Method 2 keeps all the images needed loaded at once.

So basically, the question is, it better to constantly load and unload images to keep as little loaded as possible, or to have many loaded at all times and not unload/load anything during the program? **Does the computer have a harder time loading and unloading images or keeping many images loaded at once?**

I ran looked at the task manager while running each method. CPU usage of Method 1 (loading and unloading) fluctuated between 29% and 30%, while that of Method 2 fluctuated between 28% and 29%.

It appears that keeping all the images loaded is better according to these statistics, but the reason I don't really trust them is because the program only loads seven images.

As the game gets bigger, there could be **hundreds of images loaded at once** (Method 2) or **an image loaded and unloaded nearly every frame** (Method 1). Which method is less intensive? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Depends. When loading all images needed at once you are holding them in RAM. If you don't care about memory usage you could technically load them all into memory with no issue (Method 2). If you want the best of both worlds you could have a priority loading (i.e. load X-many images and swap out the least used when you need a new one)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly you dont define 'intensive'. Having a gaming machine using 100% is good - or at least not necessarily bad. It depends on what else is going on on your system.

Second, performance analysis is done by measuring, not by thinking. YOu have measured and found an answer. Believe the answer.

In general it is faster to store things in memory that to load off disk over and over again (as your measurement shows). However you will end up using a lot of memory (no free lunches here). You dont say how much memory you have or how big the images are. Assuming each image is 10mb, then 100 of them takes 1gb. ON a modern desktop thats not a lot, on an embedded system running on an arduiono its a disaster

Why not try with 100 images and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Measurement only confirms that doing less work results in faster execution, and doing something once is faster (in a long term) than repeating the same thing multiple times (if you'll restart your animation from first frame - you'll need to reload the same images again). More of a problem here is a latency - what if your image is considerably big and it takes noticeable time to load it, will you just stop rendering until it loads? What if hard disk is under heavy load (especially HDD, SSDs are not that vulnerable to random access) and suddenly image takes 100 times more time to load? (yes can still happen with CPU, but not that likely or extremely).

If you can predict what part of data will be used soon then you'll only need to load that part till specified deadline. It is generally referred as 'streaming' and especially helpful for very big but predictable data - like audio or video files (since you always know playback speed and direction). With animations it may be more difficult - sometimes you know what animation will be played (e.g. cutscenes or trigger), sometimes they're just too general and any of them could be played. In latter case you'll probably need to keep animation data ready to prevent unwanted pauses.

If data is too big you may try to do some compression (e.g. keeping data in memory in compressed form with some fast compression algorithm and decompressing when needed - much faster than reading from slow disk; special cases like for images there may be even better solution).